# Прямая речь в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: синтаксис, спп, прямая-речь, синтаксический-разбор, авторская-пунктуация

Подскажите, является ли предложение сложноподчиненным и сколько в нем основ:

— Возьмем мы Катьку, — говорила баба, — последние наши гроши на нее пойдут, — нé на что будет соли добыть, похлебку посолить.

Comment: Полина, подскажите, что это за задание и в рамках чего. Надеюсь, не в сборниках по подготовке к ЕГЭ?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен.

**"(1) Возьмем мы Катьку, — говорила баба, — (2) последние наши гроши на нее пойдут, (3) нé на что будет соли добыть, (4)похлебку посолить".**

Это предложение состоит **из прямой речи и слов автора.** Если разбирать только прямую речь, то в ней четыре предикативные основы (и пятая  предикативная основа в словах автора).

Между предложением 1,2,3,4  бессоюзная связь, но разного характера. Между предложениями 2, 3, 4 **однородная (перечислительная)** связь, а между предложением 1 и предложениями 2,3,4  связь **неоднородная  вида "условие — следствие".**

Таким образом, прямая речь является сложным предложением **с бессоюзной (однородной и неоднородной)  связью.**

**Примечание.** Тире перед предложением 3 лучше заменить запятой , чтобы общая структура предложения была более понятной.https://pritchi.ru/id_2346

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**(1) Возьмем мы Катьку, — говорила баба, — (2) последние наши гроши на нее пойдут, (3) нé на что будет соли добыть, похлебку посолить.**

При постановке запятой (а не тире) логичнее выделить в последнем предложении однородные сказуемые ввиду их смысловой близости (можно вставить союз И).

Предложение 3 — безлично-инфинитивное (отрицательное), осложненное однородными сказуемыми. Сравнить: Не о чем говорить. Незачем туда ехать. Не на что соли купить.

Тогда получается: три основы в прямой речи и одна основа в словах автора.

Comment: Если союз пропущен, как можно говорить о подчинительной связи?

Comment: Я думаю, что союз пропущен в разговорной речи, но он подразумевается. По смыслу здесь явно условные отношения: то есть придаточная часть выражает  условие, при реализации которого может осуществиться ситуация в главной части.

Comment: Это БСП, которое по смысу сближается с СПП, в данном случае - условным.

Comment: Ну если это БСП, то ему необязательно сближаться, так как БСП может выражать значение условие — следствие. Получится: Возьмем мы Катьку — последние наши гроши на нее пойдут. Наверное, надо исправить ответ.

Comment: Это БСП неоднородного состава.Такие предложения сближаются со сложноподчинеными.

Comment: А "говорила баба" - это разве не основа? Ну и в отношении (3) и (4) - вы уверены что это две основы а не однородные члены в одной основе? Если да, на основании сего такая уверенность?

Comment: @Серж это задание из сборника для подготовки к ЕГЭ. Выяснять, кто там с кого с кем сближает - оказывать школьнику медвежью услугу. Тем более что такие подходы далеко не общеприемлемы даже на академическом уровне.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение **бессоюзное сложное**, основ я тоже насчитал 4, но те, что у Jasmin

По поводу подчиненности/сочиненности. 
Я слышал краем уха, что где-то кто-то предлагает рассматривать опушенный/подразумеваемый подчинительный союз как основание для признания предложения БСП, но это явно не школьная программа. В любом случае в вашем примере просто нет места для такого союза, даже подразумеваемого. Поэтому предложение - БСП.

*UPD: уточнил, что предложение **бессоюзное** и поскольку БСП сейчас методически противопоставляется ССП, то называть его сложносочиненным было некорректным. Просто сложное, бессоюзное.
Моя вина, исправил. Остальное - в силе.*

Вот насчет основ - тут сложнее.
поскольку слова автора являются частью предложения, то в них тоже надо смотреть на наличие основы (а она там всегда есть, поскольку при прямой речи всегда должен быть хоть один авторский глагол). С этим понятно.

А вот последнюю часть предложения **"нé на что будет соли добыть, похлебку посолить"** я рассматриваю как одну имеющую только одну основу, хотя и осложненную однородными членами. Более того, на мой взгляд, это даже не самостоятельные однородные члены  ("добыть", "посолить"), а лишь инфинитивная часть будущего времени при общем вспомогательном глаголе "будет".

//-------------
Но!!! все это справедливо только при именно таком написании, через запятую. Смотрится несколько витиевато, что вызывает сомнение в правильности пунктуации. Я бы написал без запятой. "Добыть соли картошку посолить" - это единая конструкция, означающая *добыть (соли) **с целью** посолить (картошку)*. Запятые в таком случае тут не нужны. Я понимаю, что текст Тургенева освящен традицией, Иван Сергеевич вообще отличался витиеватостью пунктуации, да и правила с тех пор уточнялись неоднократно. В любом случае включение этой фразы в сборник для подготовки к ЕГЭ вызывает вопросы. Хотя, возможно, действующие (и действовавшие) преподаватели меня поправят.

Comment: @ behemothus,а почему ССП? Здесь же нет союзов.

Comment: @Серж, БСП, конечно, спасибо.

Comment: Да нет таких предложений в ЕГЭ. Это автор вопроса просто разбирается в составе предложений. Вопрос о количестве основ в ОГЭ 9 кл.,но таких сложностей там нет. Задание было (не в ЕГЭ), скорее всего, такое: Выписать из стихотворения в прозе сложные предложения и  охарактеризовать их. И нужно было сказать, что это предложение с прямой речью, которая представляет собой ССП с 3 предикативными частями.

Comment: @Людмила у меня написано: ***пособие к ЕГЭ*** . И зачем гадать, что там скорее всего было, если оно  находится простым гуглопоиском? Здесь не могу прямую ссылку привести по техническим причинам. *Подготовка к сочинению на ЕГЭ
Авторы: Елена Попова, Любовь Черкасова* Никаких заданий "выписать" что-то там вообще нет.

Comment: *Это автор вопроса просто разбирается в составе предложений* - ну тут вам виднее. Но что касается остального, так вы только укрепили мое скептическое отношение к авторам такого задания. Формулировка "потрясная".  То есть авторские слова в счет основ не входят? Теперь так учат?!

Comment: Не видела такого пособия, а в других по подготовке к сочинению таких заданий вообще нет, могут быть разборы ошибок, а вот количество основ никто не спрашивает, это каждый ученик должен себе представлять, чтобы правильно расставить запятые. И только.

Comment: А там и не спрашивается про количество. Там вообще просто просят подумать, какие темы автор поднимает.  Людмила, про слова автора в счете основ, ответьте пожалуйста, раз уж в теме. Остальное - за рамками моей компетенции.

Comment: Разумеется, слова автора считаются за отдельную предикативную основу + 3 основы в  прямой речи, всего 4. Трудность обычно заключается в характеристике предложения: само предложение простое или сложное. Вот об этом речь, про это я и говорила, что в школе говорят просто "предложение с прямой речью", а если считают основы, то считают отдельно слова автора как отдельное простое предложение и предикативные основы прямой речи. А что нужно здесь - неизвестно.