# Как определить вид и состав сказуемого в инфинитивных предложениях?

Tags: грамматика

Названы два вида инфинитивных предложений:

**Инфинитивные предложения:** Тебе ходить. Здесь не проехать. Кому после этого верить? Как пройти на выставку? Пришел, чтобы поговорить.

**Безлично-инфинитивные предложения** (три формы): О чём (было) говорить? Не о чем (было) говорить. Есть о чем поговорить.

В учебнике написано, что в безлично-инфинитивных предложениях местоименная часть входит в основную структуру предложения, про вид сказуемого ничего не сказано.

Answer (score 1):

```
 В учебнике написано, что в безлично-инфинитивных предложениях
  местоименная часть входит в основную структуру предложения,
  про вид сказуемого ничего не сказано.
```

Всё верно, местоимённая часть входит в основную структуру на правах второстепенного члена, распространяющего сказуемое.

В определении типа (вида) сказуемого трудно ошибиться: составное глагольное сказуемое с нулевым вспомогательным глаголом, так как он избыточен, независимый инфинитив выражает:

1) значение неизбежности действия: Уж над тобою быть греху (Крылов);
2) значение необходимости, желательности действия; 3) значение возможности действия; 4) значение императивности, приказа, долженствования; 5) условно-следственные отношения; 6) риторический вопрос. К различным модальным значениям инфинитивных предложений могут присоединяться значения эмоциональные (выражение сильного желания, удивления, негодования, возмущения и т.д.): Отказать Ирине Николаевне, знаменитой артистке! (Чехов). Таким образом, они сами выражают те значения, которые придают вспомогательные глаголы.

Инфинитивные предложения: *Тебе(дополнение) ходить (сказуемое). Здесь(обст. места) не проехать (сказ.). Кому (дополнение) после этого (обстоят.+ дополнение) верить (сказ)? Как (обст.) пройти (сказ.)на выставку (обст.)? Пришел, чтобы поговорить(сказ.).*

В безлично-инфинитивных предложениях отрицательные местоимения или местоименные наречия, в вопросительно-отрицательных, или риторических, предложениях — вопросительные местоимения или местоименные наречия синтаксически подчинены инфинитиву и занимают позицию второстепенных членов (дополнений, обстоятельств), однако их отрицательное значение сообщается всему предложению и способствует выражению модального значения невозможности; например: Кипренскому было некого рисовать(Пауст.); Что ему было ответить?(Сим.); ср.:Ему было нечего ответить. Модальное значение, выраженное конструктивным способом, а не отдельной лексической единицей, сближает эти предложения с инфинитивными.

*О чём (дополнение) было говорить(сказуемое)? Не о чем (доп.) было говорить (сказ.)*.

Изменение:

Есть о чем поговорить. - фразеологизм, всё  сказ. Им есть о чём поговорить. - Им-дополнение, всё остальное - сказуемое.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1) Об инфинитивных предложениях (это просто односоставные предложения, они не являются безличными).  Связка в этих предложениях есть: Вчера здесь БЫЛО не проехать, завтра здесь БУДЕТ не проехать. Связка БЫТЬ характерна для составного именного сказуемого, но не для глагольного. Значит, это особый вид сказуемого?  2) Безлично-инфинитивные предложения. Здесь связка тоже возможна, но она относится не к инфинитиву, а к местоименной части: не о чем говорить - не о чем было говорить - не о чем стало говорить. И что это  за сказуемое? Его структура: связка + местоимение + инфинитив

Comment: Знаете, это дискуссионная тема, учёные договориться не могут, а Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то на этом сайте дал однозначный ответ. Безлично-инфинитивные предложения -  фразеологические переходные конструкции между двусоставными и односоставными безличными. Кипренскому было некого рисовать - безлично-инфинитивное, Рисовать Кипренскому было некого - двусоставное, где Рисовать - подлежащее, было некого - сказуемое. А тип сказуемого во фразеологических предложениях обычно не определяют, если уж очень надо, то смотрят, что заменяет фразеологизм - глагол - значит глагольное, имя - именное.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что перестановка изменяет статус предложения: рисовать было некого и было некого рисовать - это одно и то же, обычное актуальное членение. А вот в самых распространенных предложениях вида "я пришел, чтобы сказать"  как в школе определяют сказуемое?  Нулевая связка - это для именного сказуемого, значит, это особый вид глагольного сказуемого, но почему-то он не изучается в этой теме. Неужели никто  из учеников   никогда не спрашивал об этом, какие-то нелюбознательные стали дети. Меня, собственно говоря, именно это интересует: какое образование они получают в школе.

Comment: Такие предложения в школе для разбора не даются, а уж если где и встретится (сам школьник выберет для разбора и не сможет охарактеризовать), то говорят: примыкает к составному глагольному сказуемому, выраженному независимым инфинитивом. Примыкает - потому что похоже на него наличием инфинитива и значением.  Здесь инфинитив совмещает в себе лексическое значение и грамматическое значение модальности,которое должно было быть во вспомогательном глаголе. А придаточное предл. разбирают как безличное, инфинитивных они не знают. В контрольных же таких примеров нет.

Comment: Понимаете,  я не просто так вопрос задала, он касается определения количества предикативных основ в предложении,   вроде бы взятом из  сборника  для подготовки к ЕГЭ.  Как определить основу при наличии  однородных сказуемых в предложении "нé на что будет соли добыть, похлебку посолить". https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443692/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/443693#443693

Comment: Здесь связка "будет" относится скорее к местоимению, значит, оно входит в состав сказуемого?